# Websockets - Server-side requirements (Windows server, not Apache)

Tags: javascript, php, html, websocket, server-side

I'm trying to understand how does websocket work and I can't find any decent tutorial.
How can I work with websocket on a windows server? Does it require any extension and some PHP code? Is it a socket? or some sort of Comet new technology?

If I'm working on, for example, [www.websocket.com/game/1.htm](http://www.websocket.com/game/1.htm), and I want to have a websocket connection on this page, What url should I use?

Thanks

Comment: "you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer" please read whole http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Roy, I saw you saying "I thought it was a new version of AJAX. And it can be: websockets are the future. Microsoft had created SignalR, the framework to work with websockets while developing a website. Take a look: http://asp.net/signalr

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch17.html

In the MS ecosystem there are several options for using WebSockets:

- ASP.NET (requires that the server be windows 8 or 2012), can run in the same port than your web app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.websockets
- XSocket.NET: http://xsockets.net/
- SuperWebSocket : http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/
- Alchemy Websocket: http://alchemywebsockets.net/
- WebSocketListener : https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener

Comment: First of all, thank you!
So it's a socket. Disappointing.
So it does require an extension and a server-side code?

Comment: What did you expect? I am curious :D

Comment: There is already a new version of "ajax" : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/ . A websocket is a persistent full duplex binary connection, with a different use case than AJAX. It is more focused in "push" architectures.

Comment: And yes, it requires sever side support and coding for the handling.

Comment: You didn't understand me currently, Websocket is exactly what I need, but I thought it would be developed with Comet technology, like ajax. I want to set up websockets on my server, but, It's very complicated, server-side wide, and I still don't quite understand where to begin, and what's the best solution.

Comment: It's not complicated, Roy, take a look at SignalR. It's exactly what you need, and it's pretty easy!

Comment: Right, if you find WS difficult, try with SignalR, but remember it is like a polyfill wrapper for WebSockets, and also needs Windows 8/2012, otherwise it only has ServerSentEvents as transport... unless you are using IE, then you only have the ForeverFrame or LongPolling transports as option.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are not really requirements for a "PHP based websocket". In fact, the websocket is not really more than a simple "connection" as you always make. When you go to your url, in any way, you setup this "socket". Now the only goal you have to achieve is to make sure this connection does not "die".
This is simply achieved by setting a time limit on your script like so:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

This means the script will never time-out while "connecting" to the URL. After that you simply do your stuff as in

```
new PHPWebSocket();
```

Then you can do what ever you want with it, while keeping a connection. This is just a short story, there are other ways but I suggest you read some more about websockets and how PHP can "handle" it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you like to use WebSockets in Windows, the best choice is:
[SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

It makes the development very simple, and it also works with browsers that don't support websockets yet, using normal AJAX long-polling, or Forever Frame, etc.

Take one example, study a litle, and you'll be able to make incredible real-time websites.

It's amazing, websockets are the future!

Comment: I agree that websockets is the future (or that full duplex communication is the future). Even though I think signalr is a good option it is only an abstraction on top of the websocket protocol. You  rely on OS versions to get websockets with signalr and need win8+ on server and you do not get websockets on all clients either. But I am happy to see that MS is building somethinf like signalr even though its not my choice on the .NET stack (yet)

Comment: I agree with you about the server requirements, but about the "you do not get websockets on all clients", this is the reality of websockets at this moment. Not all browsers support them, so you need to compensate those that don't support using another technology. And SignalR does that smoothly, it's really easy to use, to understand, to develop etc. If you already have a AJAX ASP.NET application, it's too easy to migrate to SignalR.

Comment: Well, I was thinking more about other clients than browsers. Such as .NET 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 etc As well as devices such as iOS, Android. Other frameworks have websocket support there but since signalr relies on websocket as a OS feature it feel meh. However, I am very picky about this. The average demands will probably do just fine with signalr! It is a good framework!

Comment: Not to mention the ability to connect things cross-protocol (very important to me). So that I can connect things like a netduino or just raw sockets, powershell, nodejs or whatever and still communicate over the same platform (and always use full duplex sockets). As I said... I am very cranky about this ;)